# MkDocs RuntimeError: StopIteration on mkdocs serve

Tags: mkdocs

I'm trying to run MkDocs and getting a `StopIteration` error when running `mkdocs serve`. This is on a fresh MkDocs project. I've installed MkDocs, ran `mkdocs new my-project` and then `mkdocs serve`.

It appears the `file_match` variable is empty on line 345 of `config_options.py` but I can't figure out what populates `file_match`. Is there an additional step between installing MkDocs and then using it that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help. My full stack trace is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 345, in walk_docs_dir
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mkdocs", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/__main__.py", line 110, in serve_command
    serve.serve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/commands/serve.py", line 78, in serve
    config = builder()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/commands/serve.py", line 67, in builder
    config = load_config(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 151, in load_config
    errors, warnings = cfg.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 84, in validate
    self._post_validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 73, in _post_validate
    config_option.post_validation(self, key_name=key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 370, in post_validation
    for filename in self.walk_docs_dir(config['docs_dir']):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Comment: Can you add more details, please? Were there any preceding steps, info, or warning? Also, can you add a sample project to reproduce the error with settings similar to yours? What environment do you use what OS, package managers?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem with no support of python 3.7 or newer: https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1536.